# How to change the Request Date time during API Call

Tags: c#, azure, rest

I am making an API call to `Azure text Analytics` which is working fine in postman and `.Net` code. But when I use the same code with a RPA tool - Blue prism. I 
 am facing an a `trust relationship error`.
Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel.

When I further analyzed the root cause of the error - it is due to invalid current time set in the tool is two years earlier and I could not change it.

Is there way to set the request datetime in the API call code C# so the time syncs between the request and Azure server.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code (with anything sensitive stripped out) so that we can try to reproduce the issue and find a solution? Without knowing how you are calling the API endpoint it is difficult to suggest a possible solution.